# Azure AD B2C and Individual Accounts Blazor Wasm ASP .NET Core 5

Tags: azure, security, azure-ad-b2c, mysql-connector, blazor-webassembly

I' m securing my app with Azure Active Directory B2C. After login I want to give access to specific services only with registering. I want to accomplish registering with a combination of a login (Azure) parameter and a unique id (client id) that I will create in my local db and send to each client via email. Any ideas?

Comment: This sounds like something you need an API to accomplish - https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/rest-api

Answer (score 0):

In azure active directory , You can make use of identity frame work experience where you can set custom policies and integrate with a RESTful API in a user journey as in this article  suggested by [@rbrayb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9922/rbrayb).

The LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail is configured to add the REST-ValidateEmail validation technical profile.

The validation technical profile, simply checks if the email address provided by the user and in return if the email is validated the REST API return the email in lower case and the loyalty number.